# Extract filepaths and copy to pwd

Tags: regex, bash, ldd

How do can extract the path of `*.so` files and copy them to `pwd`? I think they can be extracted by regex (between `=>`  and  `(`), but do not know how.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdd63c7000)
libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f5462ffd000)
libjansson.so.4 (0x00007f5462fee000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5462fad000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f5462cd7000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f5462c53000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5462a70000)
libm.so.6 (0x00007f5462921000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f546272f000)
libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f5462706000)
libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f54626e5000)
librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f54626c5000)
libssh.so.4 (0x00007f5462655000)
libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f5462642000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f54625af000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f5462562000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f546250c000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f54624fb000)
libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f54624eb000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f54624cf000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f54632a1000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f54624c9000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f54624ae000)
libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f546232c000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f5462154000)
libhogweed.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007f546211c000)
libnettle.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007f54620e2000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f5462005000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f5461fd4000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f5461fcd000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f5461fbc000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5461fa0000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f5461f83000)
libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007f5461f3e000)
libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f5461f1b000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f5461de3000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f5461dcd000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f5461dc6000)
libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007f5461dba000)
libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007f5461d27000)
libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007f5461c7e000)
libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007f5461c46000)
libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007f5461c2d000)
libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f5461c21000)
libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007f5461bf7000)
libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007f5461be3000)
libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007f5461b95000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f5461a6c000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f5461a31000)
```

To explain how I have this problem: I compiled a binary on local linux and tried to run it on remote (unable to compile on remote server). However, it cannot be run because of lack of dependencies. So I'm copying the `*.so` files to the server.

Comment: does `awk '/=>/{print $3}'` help? This assumes no spaces in the path you want to extract and deliberately skips lines without the string `=>`. Good luck.

Comment: working with same assumptions as @shellter mentioned `sed -nE 's/^.* => ([^ ]+) .*$/\1/p'`; if there's a space in the path, no left paren in the path, and he path is always followed by a hex value in parens: `sed -nE 's/^.* => ([^(]+) \(.*$/\1/p' `

Comment: @shellter yes, `awk '/=>/{print $3}'` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk '/=>/{print $3}'`.

This assumes no spaces in the path you want to extract and deliberately skips lines without the string `=>`.

Then you can copy the files to your working directory in a couple different ways. Here is how you could with a `while` loop:

```sh
<your command> | awk '/=>/{print $3}' | while read -r file; do
    cp "$file" .
done
```